Didn't succeed trying to add class library to existing solution in .NET 7.0
I have a solution, and I am trying to add a class library to it, but I get this error message:

One or more errors where encountered while creating project
the generated project content may be incomplete.
User canceled out of save dialog

I did: right click on solution -> add -> classLibrary (net) -> choose .NET 7, and get the error

"User canceled out of save dialog" - so did you cancel? If so, that's the problem...

You can check whether the visual studio version is the latest. If it is not the latest, you can try to update it to the latest version and try to add your class library again.
